# X11 Display Variable not set when running WEKA

Tags: user-interface, weka, x11, display

When running the following command I get this error:

```
java -jar weka.jar
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at weka.gui.SplashWindow.splash(SplashWindow.java:218)
        at weka.gui.SplashWindow.splash(SplashWindow.java:262)
        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:90)
```

When checking the Display variable `echo $DISPLAY` nothing is outputted on screen.

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS codename trusty inside a VM using VirtualBox. All I Have is a CLI interface. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

X11 cannot be displayed from machine since it is a VM Ubuntu Server, with no display adapters. Weka still runs if classes are specified without GUI